# NetSSh Gem , Start method producing Connection TimedOut Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, net-ssh

In my Project, I'm testing the connection with remote Windows 2008 server, through ssh. I'm always getting the following error:

```
Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2)
  from /home/kamesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:70:in `initialize'
  from /home/kamesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:70:in `open'
  from /home/kamesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:70:in `block in initialize'
  from /home/kamesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
  from /home/kamesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:97:in `timeout'
  from /home/kamesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:67:in `initialize'
  from /home/kamesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:200:in `new'
  from /home/kamesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:200:in `start'
  from /home/kamesh/projects/RubyApp/lib/connections/ssh_connection.rb:9:in `connect'
  from (irb):5
  from /home/kamesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
  from /home/kamesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
  from /home/kamesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:4:in `require'
  from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure, what we're talking about the same thing - here's a link to [Net::SSH GitHub page](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh).

According to your error message, your ssh client can't connect to ssh server on another host.

First, you need to ensure that your server has server running. Here's a [guide](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/windows-server-2008/install-SSH-Server-Windows-Server-2008.html) about how to install it on Windows Server 2008.

Second, you need to try and `ping` your server, to ensure if it's accessible through your network at all.

If there weren't any problems on previous stages, you can try to use Net::SSH again.

Comment: Server is not responding for ping requests. but when i connect through  ssh from terminal, it is responding. Could you please tell me what error it is. and why it is occuring?